# HudLayer doesn't show up in my iOS game

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

greetings from a first time poster;
i found this site very useful a lot of times,but now there is a problem i cannot resolve,i recently made a iOS game with cocos2d,this game has scenes composed each of a game layer and a hudlayer,now,the hudlayer shows up in the xcode simulator with all the iphone models,but when i try on device it works only in the iphone 4. In an 5s for example it doesn't show up, while the game layer which contains the game works. So, when i open up the game i see only my character the level but not my joypad to move it,nor the scores ecc that should show up in the hudlayer,this is the way i implement it in a scene

header:

```
@interface GameScene : CCScene 
{
}

@property(nonatomic,weak)GameLayer *gameLayer;
@property(nonatomic,weak)HudLayer *hudLayer;

@end
```

implementation in the .m:

```
@implementation GameScene

-(id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _gameLayer = [GameLayer node];
        [self addChild:_gameLayer z:0];
        _hudLayer = [HudLayer node];
        [self addChild:_hudLayer z:1];
        _hudLayer.dPad.delegate=_gameLayer;
        _hudLayer.jPad.delegate=_gameLayer;
        _hudLayer.aPad.delegate=_gameLayer;
        _gameLayer.hud=_hudLayer; 
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

any advice?

thank you for the reply,this is the way i implemented the hud layer

header:

```
@interface HudLayer : CCLayer {

CCLabelTTF *_lifeLabel;
CCLabelTTF *_enemyLabel;


}
@property(nonatomic,weak)SimpleDPad *dPad;
@property(nonatomic, weak)SimpleJPad *jPad;
@property(nonatomic, weak)SimpleAPad *aPad;

-(void)setLifeString:(NSString *)string;
-(void)setEnemyString:(NSString *)estring;


@end
```

implementation .m:

```
@implementation HudLayer
-(id)init{
 if((self=[super init])){

    _dPad=[SimpleDPad dPadWithFile:@"pad.png" radius:50];
    _dPad.position=ccp(90, 60);
    _dPad.opacity=180;
    [self addChild:_dPad];
    _jPad=[SimpleJPad jPadWithFile:@"jumb.png" radius:30];
    _jPad.position=ccp(450, 60);
    _jPad.opacity=100;
    [self addChild:_jPad];
    _aPad=[SimpleAPad aPadWithFile:@"jumb.png" radius:30];
    _aPad.position=ccp(390, 60);
    _aPad.opacity=100;
    [self addChild:_aPad];


    //lifelabel



    _lifeLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:25];

    _lifeLabel.position = ccp(90, 260);
    [self addChild:_lifeLabel];

    //enemy label
    _enemyLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:25];

    _enemyLabel.position = ccp(380, 260);
    [self addChild:_enemyLabel];

}

return self;
}
-(void)setLifeString:(NSString *)string{

_lifeLabel.string=string;
}

-(void)setEnemyString:(NSString *)estring{
_enemyLabel.string=estring;
}

@end
```

Comment: you probably want to show a bit of the hud layer code. Any number of things could be wrong. Just based on this, it should show all the time, in every device, so something must be going on inside the hud layer class.

Comment: edited with hudlayer code,thank you for your reply

Comment: @john, make a new project with the same HUD implementation and test. if it doesn't work then share your sample project here.

Comment: what you mean to share the sample project,is it possible to load a project in the site?the code anyway is all the one i posted,the only thing that i didn't posted is that i create a HUdLayer object named *hud in the gamelayer class,and nothing more,could it be the fact that i use a old version of cocos2d?i use version 2.x,but even if was for the version shouldn't it not work even in the simulator? thank you for your time again